# How to make elements take up all available space?

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, godot4

With Godot 4, a lot is changed and older tutorials are hard with it to follow for new comers. For example, I could not find way to set margin constants in margineContainer. I found that under theme Overrides. Now I can not find a way to make a few buttons take all available space in HBoxContainer.

In the inspectors container sizing under Layout seems not to effect elements inside it.

How to make those buttons take all available space? How to make them centered? How to make them expand and adapt on different screens?

Edit : Found solution. Will have to set expand property 'On' on each elements inside the container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Will have to set expand property 'On' as needed from Layouts container sizing, on each elements inside the container.